# Page is getting refreshed when window opens for file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jsp page where I have some fields for uploading images.I am using jquery.fileupload.js for uploading images on my jsp page. When I am clicking on a button to upload image, window for browsing image is getting opened but in the background the page gets refreshed.

Please someone tell me that why is it getting refreshed.

Following is the html code for html button.

```
    <button role="button" value="Upload" onclick="$(this).next().click()">Upload</button> 
<input id="IMAGE_125_625" class="image-file" type="file"
name="file" style="display: none;" 
data-url="/admin/product/image/upload?imageSize=IMAGE_125&imageId=625" 
accept="image/*" />
```

And following is the javascript code is file uploading

```
$(".image-file")
    .each(function() {
            $(this)
                .fileupload(
                    {
                     dataType : "json",
                    acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/i,
                    done : function(e,data) {
                    var src = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/image/load/"
                        + data.result.link;
            src += (((src.indexOf("?") !== -1) ? "&":"?")+randomNumber(10000));
            $("#img_"+ e.target.id).attr("src",src);
                        }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Show relevant code please

Comment: Is there a 'target=_blank' attribute on it?

Comment: Probably you have defined some handler that submit the form to the some class which is added to the upload button? :)

Comment: I have pasted the code